# Powershell Want to create a property by switch and return to a csv

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to pull default gateway info from `get-wmiobject` and then add a new property to an object, using switch to fill in the info, by using a `Foreach-object` within a `foreach`.   I'm knocking my head on the wall.  Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

I can export the CN and the DefaultIpgateway fine, but the location property and the `$location` variable isn't updating.  I want to get that `$location` variable to switch and then put the data into Location Property of `$output`.

I'm very new to Powershell. Any help is appreciated.

```
$hostname = Get-Content -path C:\workspace\location_project\Workspace_818\pcs.txt 
$output = foreach ($h in $hostname) {
    #get-wmiobject will get the comptuer info for each system. 
    get-wmiobject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -filter "IPEnabled=TRUE" -computername $H | foreach-object {
        new-object PSObject -property @{
           "CN" = $h 
           "DefaultIPGateway" = $_.DefaultIPGateway[0] 
           "Location" = $location ## = $output."DefaultIPGateway"[0])
       }
        switch ($output."DefaultIPGateway") {
           10.10.1.2{$location = "Location1"}
           10.10.1.20{$location = "Locaiton2"}
        }                           
        select-object DefaultIPGateway, CN, Location
    }
}
$output | Export-csv C:\workspace\CN_Gateway_Loc_Get2.csv -NoTypeInformation -force
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this. You need to get the location first. So I set `$location` to the result of switch. Then I create the pscustomobject with the parameters you wanted. You don't need a Select-Object because the three attributes are the only attributes in the object.

```
$hostname = Get-Content -Path C:\workspace\location_project\Workspace_818\pcs.txt 
$output = foreach ($h in $hostname) {
    #get-wmiobject will get the comptuer info for each system. 
    Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter "IPEnabled=TRUE" -ComputerName $H `
    | ForEach-Object -Process {
        $location = switch ($_.DefaultIPGateway) {
            10.10.1.2  { 'Location1'; break }
            10.10.1.20 { 'Locaiton2'; break }
            default    { 'unknown' }
        }    

        [pscustomobject] @{
            "CN" = $h 
            "DefaultIPGateway" = $_.DefaultIPGateway[0] 
            "Location" = $location 
        }
    }
}
$output | Export-csv C:\workspace\CN_Gateway_Loc_Get2.csv -NoTypeInformation -force
```

Comment: That works!  Once I applied it to my script with a little tweaking it ran beautifully.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

In your sample code, you add `$location` the object, when its still empty. You have to set `$location` before you add it to the object.

Further considerations:

- use `Get-CimInstance` over `Get-WmiObject` because it uses WinRM to connect to remote computers by default and acceppt `CimSession` as input, which is has the lowest footprint. And maybe most important: It queries the computers in parallel which makes the complete script in scale suuuuper fast!
- `Get-CimInstance` (as well as `Get-WmiObject`) accepts multiple CimSessions/ComputerNames as input, hence you don't need the `foreach`.
- `[PSCustomObject]` is faster then `New-Object`

After applying the improvements, your code would look somewhat like this:

```
$hostname = Get-Content -path C:\workspace\location_project\Workspace_818\pcs.txt 
$csvPath = 'C:\workspace\CN_Gateway_Loc_Get2.csv'

$CimSessions = New-CimSession -ComputerName $hostname
$NetworkAdapterConfiguration = Get-CimInstance -CimSession $CimSessions -ClassName Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter "IPEnabled=TRUE"

$output = foreach ($adapter in $NetworkAdapterConfiguration) {
    switch ($adapter.DefaultIPGateway[0]) {
        '10.10.1.2' {$location = 'Location1'}
        '10.10.1.20' {$location = 'Location2'}
        default {$location = 'Unknown'}
    }
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        ComputerName = $adapter.PSComputername
        DefaultIPGateway = $adapter.DefaultIPGateway[0] 
        Location = $location
    }
}

$output | Export-Csv -Path $csvPath -NoTypeInformation -Force
```

If that works for you, I highly recommend to convert your [script into a tool (Cmdlet)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KprrLkjPq_c). Make a function that allows `ComputerName` and `CimSession` as input. Output would be your already defined object. This would allow anyone to use the tool as he needs to use it (instead of, how you want them to use it). If your new Cmdlet is called `Get-DefaultGateway` you can do things like this:

```
Get-DefaultGateway -ComputerName (Get-ADComputer).Name | Out-GridView
```

or

```
$CimSessions = Get-Clipboard | New-CimSession
Get-DefaultGateway -CimSession $CimSessions | Export-Csv -Path $env:TEMP\export.csv
```

Comment: Minor nitpick, cmdlets (compiled .Net) and functions (native PowerShell) are different. So it would be more precise to say _"...convert your script into a function"_ and _"If your new function is called Get-DefaultGateway..."_  Also just a note that both 'Get-CimInstance` and `[PSCustomObject]` are only available PowerShell 3+.

Comment: Thank you for the Help Vrdse.   I ran into authentication errors when I attempted to run cimsession.  I will have to talk to my admin about that.  however I will look into it more to streamline my command. thanks for the help!

Comment: Sorry benh, I didn't see this until I had posted.  Points taken. :)